# application class organisation

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm developing a simple application which, when a button is clicked, opens up another window as a popup: after the button is clicked, it disappears leaving only the second window on the screen. When this new window is closed the original button should reappear, but I'm a bit unsure what is the best way forward. I tried to design the app with different classes: a MyUi class which contains just the button, a NewWindow class dealing with the new window and a Component class which essentially has the info that goes onto that new window. The problem I'm having with this approach is with the ability to hide and show the original button. Let's look at some code.

```
MyUi.java has the button:
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        final NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
       final UploaderComponent uploaderComponent = new UploaderComponent();
        //final TextField name = new TextField();
       // name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

      final Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //button.setVisible(false);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getUI().addWindow(newWindow.getWindow());
                newWindow.getWindow().setContent(uploaderComponent.formLayout);             
            }
        });


        layout.addComponents(button);
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);

        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
    public void resetButton(){
        //button.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here is the NewWindow.java instead

```
public class NewWindow {
    //public static final Sizeable.Unit PIXELS;
        Window window = new Window();
        public NewWindow(){
            window.setStyleName("wrappingWindow");
            window.setWidth("620px");
            window.center();
            window.addCloseListener(new CloseListener()
            {               
                @Override
                public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("window closed");

                }
            });

        }
        public Window getWindow(){
            return window;
        }
}
```

and the component class:

```
public class UploaderComponent extends CustomComponent {
    final TextField name;
    final TextField surname;
    //final Label div;
    final VerticalLayout formLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    public UploaderComponent(){

        formLayout.addStyleName("myLayout");



        name = new TextField();
        surname = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Type your name here:");
        surname.setCaption("Type your surname here:");
        formLayout.addComponents(name, surname);

    }
}
```

With this set up, I can get the button to disappear when it is clicked pretty easily with `button.setVisible(false);` but I'm finding it really hard to get it back because I would have to call a function from the Window class when the close button is called, and this function will have to access the button that sits inside the UI class...bit messy. Is this the best way?

Comment: You can either add a method like showButton() to your UI class and then call this from your window as needed. The other way would be to create a listener which then shows/hides your button as needed (Bot the overhead is much larger)

Comment: thanks, yes I thought about having a method in the UI class, but methods usually have to reside outside the init function and the button is declared inside that init function, so I either add a getter to get the button out of there or perhaps I declare it to sit outside that function

Comment: So make that button a property of the UI class...